# d3.js v5 mixed baseline tspans

Tags: d3.js

My d3 visual has several different lines plotted on it, and instead of creating a legend, I want to place some labels right into the coordinate space. To this end, I'm trying to append some svg tspans. The text for each label is:

Group 1 a

Group 1 b

Group 1 c

I have three lines, and so three labels will be needed. The "Group 1" part shall be normal, and the letters "a b and c" should be subscript. After a bit of research I learned that tspans have a `basline-shift` attribute. I tried:

```
svg.append('text')
    .append('tspan')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('baseline-shift', 'sub')
    .text('Group 1c');
```

The tspan appears, but it seems like I can only get it to accept *all* normal or *all* subscript text-- not a mix of both.

### Question

Given my goal as detailed above, how should I best modify my implementation of mixed tspans? Am I correct in choosing tspans for this task? To my knowledge there is no [Unicode for subscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Latin_and_Greek_tables) b and c, which makes it seem like tspan is possibly the only solution for my particular task.

Comment: isn't `tspan` a child of `text`?

Comment: @riov8 yea, that helped

Answer (score 0):

In hindsight, this seems obvious, but I will show one way I found that works. And instead of deleting this question, I will post my solution to it, because there seems to be very few / no similar questions. Tspans and sub/superscripts can be tricky, so hopefully this will help someone. Once riov8 showed me I neglected to append the parent `text` I was able to do more effective troubleshooting.

Adding `.html()` with `<tspan>` tags can give us the mix of normal and subscript:

```
svg.append('text')
    .append('tspan')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .html('Group 1 <tspan baseline-shift=sub>c</tspan>');
```

Comment: It seems to me that you're bending over backwards, you don't need `html` here (which, by the way, uses `innerHTML` internally and only in modern browsers will work in SVGs...): the combo `<text>` and `<tspan>` work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/w8fe47yx/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Oh, well how about that! Thanks for sharing, that does seem preferable.